# while calculating datediff stored procedure getting syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[IBS_fetchreqVehicleinPodiumtestnew1]
   @locid INTEGER = NULL
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @TodayMinus7Days DATETIME
Declare @krrt integer
Declare @DT integer
   SET @TodayMinus7Days = getdate()-7

   SELECT  
       t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode
       if t.status=3
       begin
       @krrt=datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate, GETDATE())
         end
         else
         if t.status=4
         begin
         @krrt=datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate, t.t.KeyRoomDate)
         end
         if t.status=5
         begin 
         @dt=datediff(minute,t.paydate,t.Deldate)
         end
   FROM    
       dbo.Transaction_tbl t
   WHERE   
       ([status] IN (3,4) AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
       OR 
       ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3 AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
   ORDER BY  
       paydate
END
```

while executing stored procedure if the corresponding Tbarcode status is 3 then i want to show difference between paydate and current time ti..if status is 4 then i want to show diffence between t.paydate and t.keyroomdate ,if status is 5 then i want to show differnce between that particulardate...but while executing this stored procedure getting error.

Comment: Please also add the error message

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `if` is a flow control statement. You can't put one in the middle of a `SELECT` statement. Also, you can't combine data retrieval and variable assignments in a single `SELECT`. Since you don't use `@krrt` and `@dt` anywhere else in the stored procedure and they're local variables, why are you attempting to assign values to them?

Comment: Use Case statements to do that logic.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting to retrieve these `DATEDIFF` results as another column in your result set, it should just be:

```
   SELECT  
       t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode
       datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate,
             CASE t.Status
                WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
                WHEN 4 THEN t.KeyRoomDate
             END) as KRRT,
       datediff(MINUTE,t.PayDate,
             CASE t.Status
                WHEN 5 THEN t.DelDate
             END) as DT
   FROM    
       dbo.Transaction_tbl t
   WHERE   
       ([status] IN (3,4) AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
       OR 
       ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3
         AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
   ORDER BY  
       paydate
```

Comment: i want to get out put like this: tbarcode,t.plateno,t.delecode,KRRT,DT, KRRT means if status=3 then show diff between paydate and current date,if status=4 then show diff between paydate and keyroom date,Dt means diff between paydate and deldate

Comment: @user3262364 - updated it to be two separate columns.

Comment: i mean when status=3 and status=4 then i want to return only one result that is KRRT

Comment: @user3262364 - you can't have a *single* query that produces different result shapes. The number, name and types of the columns the query produces is fixed. Also, consider that in general, a query would be expected to return *multiple* rows, and different rows could have different statuses - so both columns have to exist.

Comment: while executing that getting error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.its related here:datediff(MINUTE,t.PayDate,
                WHEN 5 THEN t.DelDate
             END) as DT

Comment: @user3262364 - sorry, forgot to include the `CASE` line inside the second `DATEDIFF`. Remember - I don't have your database, so I can't test these queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter procedure [dbo].[IBS_fetchreqVehicleinPodiumtestnew1]
   @locid INTEGER = NULL
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @TodayMinus7Days DATETIME
   SET @TodayMinus7Days = getdate()-7

   SELECT  
       t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode
       ,case 
            when t.status=3 then datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate, GETDATE())
        when t.status=4 then datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate, t.t.KeyRoomDate)
        else null
    end AS krrt
    , case
        when t.status=5 then datediff(minute,t.paydate,t.Deldate)
        else null
    end as DT
   FROM    
   dbo.Transaction_tbl t
   WHERE   
   ([status] IN (3,4) AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
   OR 
   ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3 AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
   ORDER BY  
   paydate
```

END